# Have IIS not respond if there are no host headers

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

All of the sites I have hosted in IIS have host header bindings, and I've disabled the Default Website. Right now, if someone hits `http(s)://<ipaddress>` they still get a 404 response from the server.

Is there a way to get IIS to not even respond to a request with no host headers (or a request with host headers that aren't bound)?  On nginx, commonly you'll have the server return a status of 444 if no bindings are found, which instructs the server to drop the connection with no response.